# SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, selinux

I kept getting the following notice in apache log when I start apache http server 2.2:

```
SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
```

even though I disabled selinux already.  what's wrong?

Comment: you _need_ getting, or you _keep_ getting? Also, [stop disabling SELinux](http://stopdisablingselinux.com/)

Comment: @dawud: kept getting

Comment: Can you please add the output of `sestatus` and `cat /etc/selinux/config` to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the output of sestatus and probably `/var/log/audit/audit.log` help.

Also just want to add if `httpd` directory resides in a user home directory then this boolean need to be enabled.

`setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1`